# Next day or next row index in Pandas Data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to find a way to get the next day (next row in this case) in a Pandas dataframe.  I thought this would be easy to find but Im struggling.

**Starting Data**:

```
    ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts.columns = ['Val']
ts['Week'] = ts.index.week
ts

             Val       Week
2000-01-01  -0.639345   52
2000-01-02  1.294537    52
2000-01-03  1.181486    1
2000-01-04  -0.011694   1
2000-01-05  -0.224887   1
2000-01-06  -0.493120   1
2000-01-07  1.439436    1
2000-01-08  1.017722    1
2000-01-09  1.125153    1
2000-01-10  0.209741    2
```

**Subset of the data:**

```
tsSig = ts[ts.Val>1.5].drop_duplicates(subset='Week')

tsSig.head()


              Val   Week
2000-01-24  2.215559    4
2000-02-09  1.561941    6
2000-02-24  1.645916    8
2000-03-16  1.745079    11
2000-04-10  1.570023    15
```

I now want to use the index from my `tsSig` subset to find the next day in `ts`and then create a new column `ts['Val_Dayplus1']` showing values from the 25th(`-0.309811`), 10th(`-1.644814`) etc.

I am trying things like `ts.loc[tsSig.index].shift(1)` to get next day but this is obviously not correct....

**Desired output:**

```
                 Val  Val_Dayplus1  Week
2000-01-24  2.215559  -0.309811      4
2000-02-09  1.561941  -1.644814      6
2000-02-24  1.645916   -0.187440     8
```

(for all rows in tsSig.index)

**Edit:**

This appears to give me what I need in terms of shifting the date index on `tsSig.index`.  I would like to hear of any other ways to do this as well.

```
ts.loc[tsSig.index + pd.DateOffset(days=1)]
 tsSig['Val_Dayplus1'] = ts['Val'].ix[tsSig.index + pd.DateOffset(days=1)].values
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work this one out so sharing the answer:

```
    ts.loc[tsSig.index + pd.DateOffset(days=1)]
    tsSig['Val_Dayplus1'] = ts['Val'].ix[tsSig.index + pd.DateOffset(days=1)].values

tsSig

                Val Week  Val_Dayplus1
2000-02-15  1.551125    7   -0.102154
2000-02-24  1.525402    8   -0.009776
2000-03-11  1.801845    10  0.832837
2000-03-22  1.546953    12  0.377510
2000-04-17  1.568720    16  -0.258558
2000-06-04  1.646147    22  0.853044
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but in general, you can index through a pandas data frame by using `df.iloc[ROWS,COLS]`. So, in your case, for an index `i` in a for loop, you could index `ts.iloc[i+1,:]`, to get all of the info from the next row in the `ts` dataframe.

Comment: I have added data so please show me what you mean.  I've given desired output.